# Reply mail structure information: how to retrieve sent and received information

Tags: php, email, imap

I need create a system using IMAP that can read the replies inside the inbox, I don't need a piece of code, but an explaination of how a reply mail is structured.
At this moment I'm sending multiparts emails and my intencion is to put the 2 information that I need inside the boundary (a 87 chars identifier plus the user mail) and add string like:

```
=======================================================
Reply above the previous line
```

But my doubts are:

- What if for some insanes reasons the user uses the same identifier
  inside the reply, how can I identify in a safe way where the reply starts?
- has it got sense to save the info inside the boundary or once that the user reply those information will be lost from the header?
- How can I identify if the reply mail is plain text or HTML or both?

If some one has got some suggestion even about where to put those information I will be glad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no standard for the structure of a reply email. It's not usually done using multipart email, it just uses human-readable text, often with `>` prefixes to denote quoted text. This allows replies to be interspersed inline with the quoted material.

The only standard features of replies are a couple of headers:

```
In-Reply-To: <ID>
```

and

```
References: <ID1>, <ID2>, <ID3>, ...
```

`In-Reply-To` contains the message ID of the message that was replied to. `References` is a growing list of message IDs -- when you reply, you take the original message's reference list and append the ID of the message being replied to at the end.

See [RFC 5322](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322.txt) for more details about these headers.

Comment: So the mime of the reply is plain/text and it will lose the boundary, doesn't it?

Comment: The MIME type of the reply can be anything you like. If you want, you could put the original in as an `application/rfc822` attachment, but that's not the usual approach. It's typically only used in bounce messages.